# Excel VBA: Manipulate Shockwave Flash Property

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a little project to make a 'memeplayer' in Excel with YouTube videos - here's a screenshot of the spreadsheet

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCfMu.jpg]

The code I'm attempting to use is below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PlaySamsMemes()

Dim sChosenTitle As String
Dim rngVideoData As Range
Dim lFinalRow As Long
Dim sLookupValue As String

lFinalRow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
sChosenTitle = Range("F4").Value
Set rngVideoData = Range("B2:C" & lFinalRow)
sLookupValue = Application.VLookup(sChosenTitle, rngVideoData, 2, False)

Memeplayer.SetVariable("Movie", sLookupValue)

End Sub
```

I'd be really grateful if you could tell me how to get the script to play nice with the embedded Shockwave Flash that I've named 'Memeplayer' in the Excel interface. The line I'm using to try and make it run is:

Memeplayer.SetVariable("Movie", sLookupValue)

but it just returns an 'Object required' error (Runtime Error 424). I've not worked with shapes and objects much as yet and I've no idea how to fix it. Help me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've since solved the problem. I just hadn't Set the Object correctly - couldn't figure out the heirachy for it. The code is below:

```
Set MemePlayer = Sheets(1).MemePlayer

MemePlayer.Movie = sLookupValue
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA has many limitations and trying to do something like this in Excel is probably not the best way to go about it. However, here are 2 websites that might shed some light on your problem:

1. http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/01/11/embed-youtube-videos-excel/ - this should help most I think
2. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DownloadFile.aspx (from the website: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-use-vba-play-sound-clip-website-t3893819.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Grim but to get to this point I've already done everything in Chandoo's post. I was actually building on that post.